# Вычисление максимума из средних значений

Tags: sql, сервер

Уважаемые чатеры, подскажите, пожалуйста. Как можно вычислить максимальное значение из предварительно посчитанных средних значений? Насколько я знаю, выражение типа `MAX(AVG)` не работает. И встречный вопрос: как можно разбить данные не используя предложение `GROUP BY`?

Comment: "максимальное значение из предварительно посчитанных средних значений" значит, что средние значения уже посчитаны и находятся в каком-то поле таблицы? Тогда `select max(avgvalue) from tab`, где avgvalue -- поле таблицы tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX (at.a)
FROM (
     SELECT AVG(field1) AS a
     FROM [table]
     GROUP BY ..
) AS at
```

Comment: Да это решение роботает, но у меня следующие ограничения:
1-е решить эту задачу не пребигая к: подзапросам, дополнительных таблицам, курсорорам;
1-е решить эту задачу не пребигая к: подзапросам, дополнительных таблицам, курсорорам, GROUP BY явно.

Answer (score 0):

[Агрегатная функция от агрегатных функций.](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function.html)

Comment: Агрегатная функция от агрегатных функций - это хорошо пока не стоит ограничение следующего типа: нелязя использовать ни подзапросов, ни дополнительных таблиц, ни курсоров; сдеся я выход нашол используя конструкцию SELECT TOP 1 WIHT TIES, но как быть когда к рание приведанным ограничениям добавляю, что нелязя явно использовать предложение GROUP BY??? http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function/page2.html

Comment: Дополнительные ограничения - это что-то надуманное, похоже на учебное задание. Что касается TOP 1 WITH TIES, то это нестандартная конструкция от MSSQL, и на других СУБД работать не будет.